# Creation of virtual directory failed to update applicationhost.config (in my documents)

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have moved a Visual Studio 2013 project (from my user's document folder - don't ask, it was somebody else who did this) to a more neutral folder on another drive.

However, on one of projects in the solution I get an error saying creation of the virtual directory failed to update applicationhost.config in the IISExpress folder, which is also in the my documents folder.

I have tried deleting the *.user files and I've tried changing UseIISExpress to false in the csproj file but I still get this error.

How do I fix this as I do not know how to move IISExpress and all fixes I've seen for this issue revolve around the previous two solutions I've tried.

thanks.

Comment: You moved the project, so broke the sync between IIS Express configuration file and the project. Use Jexus Manager to generate a report, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html which should show you some hints. I also have a blog post on the technical details behind, https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not install some software. It seems a little bit flaky that moving a project causes all this, because what if somebody else downloaded the project? is there not a means of simply updating whatever is pointing to this folder to look at a different folder?

Comment: You can challenge Microsoft's design but since Visual Studio 2015 the design does change, which stores the IIS Express configuration file in .vs folder of your solution. By using VS2013, you have been left behind for almost 5 years.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really explain why it fails to write when IIS is in the same folder as it's always been and I'm the same user as I've always been...